# How to append multiple columns from two select sub queries together using the same primary key?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables I need to join into a view. My first table, called ttddocseg is a history of all segments of a flight itinerary. It will contain a departure city code and arrival city code in this table, among other irrelevant info. My second table is a city table that has a connection to the segment table on the city code key. What I want to be able to do is pull in the extra city information from the city table into a single view with the segment transaction data, when the 'key' (city code) is used twice: the arrival and departure city.

Example:

```
SELECT arvlctycode, dpartctycode FROM ttddocseg
```

Yields:

```
DFW  ,DEN  
DEN  ,ORD    
LAX  ,DEN    
ORD  ,LAX      
DEN  ,DCA  
...
```

And

```
SELECT ctycode, ctyname FROM trfcty
```

Yields:

```
DFW ,Dallas/Fortworth
DEN ,Denver
LAX ,Los Angeles
...
```

So my desired output would be, when joining the segment and city tables:

```
DFW, Dallas/Fortworth, DEN, Denver
DEN, Denver, ORD, Chicago/OHARE 
...
```

So in theory I would join two subqueries that each joins the tables, one on arrival city code and another on destination city code, and then put those sets of columns next to each other, order by my tables key to make sure the arrival/dest pair up properly. Everything I have tried has not yet worked though. My best efforts so far:

```
select
    (
        select a.ctycode, b.arvlctycode, b.arvldate, b.actualmile, b.aircrrcode, b.tdtrxnum, b.tddocnum, b.segnum
        from trfcty a inner join ttddocseg b on a.client = b.client and a.ctycode = b.arvlctycode
        where a.client = 'TT' and ctytype = 'A'
        --order by b.tdtrxnum, b.tddocnum, b.segnum
    ) AS Arrival,
    (
        select a.ctycode, b.dpartctycode , b.dpartdate, b.actualmile, b.aircrrcode, b.tdtrxnum, b.tddocnum, b.segnum
        from trfcty a inner join ttddocseg b on a.client = b.client and a.ctycode = b.dpartctycode 
        where a.client = 'TT' and ctytype = 'A'
        --order by b.tdtrxnum, b.tddocnum, b.segnum
    ) AS Departure
```

The commented out section 'Order by' is what I tried to do to make sure the pairing of arrival/departure city stay lined up, as those are the primary keys for the segment table.

I'm getting errors doing that, of course, but the idea behind it is clear I think. I just don't know how to do it the right way.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. "I'm getting errors ..." doesn't help us. Your code seems to have an awful lot of columns that you didn't mention in your cursory explanation of your data. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT s.arvlctycode, s.dpartctycode, ca.cityname, cs.cityname
FROM ttddocseg s JOIN
     trfcty ca
     ON s.arvlctycode = ca.ctycode JOIN
     trfcty cd
     ON s.dpartctycode = cs.ctycode;
```

This returns the cities associated with each of the codes.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem. I didn't consider joining the same table twice, thinking it would cause other problems.